# What is the REST style for getSomethingByAnother() method

Tags: javascript, rest, web, nodes

I have a Node.js REST API service and I have a resouce - `Link` for example.

- To get all links I use `GET /links`
- To submit new link I use `POST /links`
- To get one link by linkid I use `GET /links:id`

Each link have an array of `Tags` and I need a REST style URI to get the  links by tag value. What will be REST style URI in this case ?

Comment: `GET /tags/:tagID/links`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you create the answer to make me close the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the links of a certain tag you can define the following route:

`/tags/:tagID/links`

And for getting tags of a certain link:

`/links/:linkID/tags`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

`GET  /links/:id/tags`

that should return all the tags related to the link with id ":id"

If you like to work with your tags as a separated thing you could do it like this:

`GET /tags` ==> retrieve all tags.

`GET /tags/:id` ==> retrieve tag with id..

`GET /tags/links/:id`

Also resftull is not strict, and some times, the resource, or action that you need to execute does not fit in that schema, and you can create a custom method:

`GET /tags/get-for-link-id/:id` => retrieve tags related to a link

That example is pointless, but consider that you are having a complicated route with so much params eg:

`GET /tags?q=return&state=active&sort=date` if this request is repeated so much times, for your api customer it would be pleasant to have a custom alias like `GET /tags/activeByDate`

Answer (score 0):

It depends. TYou can do something like `/blah:{tagId}/` (which is perfectly valid URI as well). Or you can do `/links/?tagID={id}` and so on. I don't prefer the already mentioned hierarchical URI `/tags/{id}/links`, I think a flat URI is much better. If the relationship has attributes as well, then you can use `/tag-link-relationships/{relationshipId}` or `/tag-link-relationships/tag:{tagId}/` or `/tag-link-relationships/?tag={tagId}` etc...

From client perspective the URI structure does not matter, because the client follows the hyperlinks the service responds with (aka. uniform interface / HATEOAS constraint).

*off: Almost every day we got this question, at least try to search next time.*